# Compare value with 1st and 2nd column print corresponding 3rd column

Tags: unix, awk, numbers

I have file like this

```
01 10 a
11 20 b
21 30 c
31 40 d
41 50 e
```

I want to input a number and compare with 1st and 2nd column and to print corresponding 3rd column

For example if I enter 23 it should display c, if I enter 45 it should display e

Comment: What if you input "1" vs "01"? Are you looking for a string or RE or numeric comparison? Is your comparison for equality or greater-then or between or something else?

Answer (score 2):

`egrep "^${DIGIT_1}[0-9] ${DIGIT_2}[0-9]" file | awk '{print $3}'`

`DIGIT_1` is `2` and `DIGIT_2` is `3` in your example

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter the number"
read num
while read line
do
set -- $line

    if [ $num -ge $1 ] && [ $num -le $2 ] ;then
            echo $3
            exit 1
    fi
done < filename
echo "not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `awk` approach

```
cat file
01 10 a
11 20 b
21 30 c
31 40 d
41 50 e
```

```
i=40
```

```
awk 'inp<=$2 {f=$3;exit} END {print $3}' inp=$i file
d
```

Comment: "a b c d e" is also in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

another **awk** approach

```
awk -v d=<yournumber> '{dt=int(d/10);du=d-dt*10;c1=int($1/10);c2=int($2/10);if(dt==c1&&du==c2)print $3}' <yourfile>
```

Comment: i assumed that the units digit in first column need not always be 0; similarly for column 2

Answer (score 0):

In a simple [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script:

```
% awk -vfirst=2 -vsecond=3 '
$1 ~ first && $2 ~ second { print $3 }
' file-like-this
c
```

---

```
% awk -vfirst=4 -vsecond=5 '
$1 ~ first && $2 ~ second { print $3 }
' file-like-this
e
```

---

You can get `awk` to determine the first and second digits of a number like so:

```
% awk -vnumber=45 '
BEGIN { first = int(number / 10); second = number % 10 }                           
$1 ~ first && $2 ~ second { print $3 }
' file-like-this
e
```